# 1 for 0 arguments errors formtastic, mongomapper and rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongomapper, formtastic

While experimenting with mongomapper in a rails 3.1 app I decided to also have a look at using formtastic as well. This is more than likely down to my own incompetence but I am getting a strange error that I can't get to the bottom of

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

It is being caused by the form.inputs line in the form below

```
<%= semantic_form_for @product do |form| %>
   <%= form.inputs :name %>
   <%= form.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

The model

```
class Product
   include MongoMapper::Document

   key :name, String
end
```

Originally I has tried using `<%= form.inputs %>` on a more complex model but no form fields were generated so started adding them explicitly and ran into the same problem I have recreated with this simple model. I read in the documentation that formtastic is quite ActiveRecord-centric. Is this a compatibility issue or is it just something silly that I'm missing?

I'm using

rails 3.1, 
ruby 1.9.2,
mongo_mapper 0.9.2,
formtastic 2.0.0.rc4 ( I originally tried rc5)

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace?  You'll probably have to dig into formtastic's source to see what it was expecting.

Comment: I actually lodged an issue. There is more information here https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/676

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been resolved by the author of the gem, thanks Justin! The 2.0.2 release should work without any problems

More details can be found here

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/676#issuecomment-2304425